# How can we detect if a request to a server was sent from a site embedded in an iframe?

Tags: http, next.js, safari, http-headers

I need to block anyone who tries to access a web page directly via URL link, but still allow access if the web page is embedded within an iframe. To achieve this, I have relied on the `Sec-Fetch-Site` header. If my Next.js server detects that the value of the header is not `cross-site`, then I simply block the request.

This method works perfectly, except that Safari browser (up to version 16.4) does not support it.  https://caniuse.com/mdn-http_headers_sec-fetch-site

Is there any way to achieve the same behavior on Safari versions 15 to 16.3?

Comment: Have you tried checking the referrer?  Note, none of this would protect against someone using curl or similar as they could get set any header to any value.

Comment: @kicken Yes, and it works in most cases. But, there are some cases when`Referer` value equals to host value. At the same time, `Sec-Fetch-Site` value is `same-origin` despite I clearly know that the request comes from an iframe and the iframe is on the other website. I can see the same values in the browser. So far, I could not identify that causes this behaviour.

Comment: I have figure out why the `Sec-Fetch-Site` and `Referer` indicated thaw the request was made from direct link but not from the iframe. I have default language en but I did requests from browser with different language. Therefore, Next.js did redirect from and to the same page but just added additional param in url that indicate language. So, everything is ok with headers.

Comment: But still there must be a fallback solution as the headers can be cut of from a request. And the we will not be able to detect who made the particular request.